# How to resolve a buffered values issue in Websocket Rxjs? Sending a message doesn't go to the server but gets stored in buffer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am using Websocket Rxjs in my application. My connection gets established with the server and after subscribing to it I receive all the data in an array. Now when I try to send the some data back to the server, it just doesn't send, it get's stored in the buffer array of destination object of websocket observable (screenshot below). I am sharing the snippet of the code also.

```
 import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const subject = webSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

subject.subscribe({
  next: msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg),
  error: err => console.log(err), 
  complete: () => console.log('complete') 
});


// Upon clicking a button I send this to the sever. You can see it in the screenshot.
subject.next({
    "action" : "read",
    "id" : 1595
});
```

[image]

My connection remains active though. It doesn't gets closed but still I am facing this issue. What could be the issue with this? Is it something with the backend ? If yes, then what could it be ? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: Do you see any activity in the Network > WS tab of dev tools?

Comment: @BizzyBob Yes I can see request going to the server and receiving the data in WS tab but when I send anything, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is in your websocket server, but to be sure try instead  to connect to a test server like the echo server of Postman:
wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw

In each time the client sends a message to this server it will send it back to the client directly.

By the way: Postman now has the possibility yo to connect to your websocket server and test it.

Here you can read how to do that:
https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-websocket-apis/

Comment: just seeing this, and downloaded the latest PM desktop app. The websocket thing works well. Following the guide here: https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/websockets/documentation/14057978-712d684f-c252-4bd9-a7a6-6a893e41adea?entity=folder-ef871df7-789f-41e7-b31d-8ce095f942a3&branch=&version=